# Buffalo explanation

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Could anybody please  explain in detail  the sentence

> "Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo."

I have seen the [wikipedia pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) but am unable to get it properly.